# Manipulating two html files with one JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple game using html and javascript, I have my index page which prompts the user for the number of players, then I would want to display as many input fields as the players' number.
My problem now is that when the user types in a number, he gets redirected to another html page to insert the names, **I need the players number value**, but I can't seem to get it right, as when I try to use the same app.js file for the two html pages it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your code?

Comment: State is not maintained across web pages; you'll need to pass the information along to the next page as a URL parameter, or store it in localStorage so the following page can retrieve it, or change your application to a SPA-type structure (where it's technically always the same "page".)

Comment: Perhaps, you can share your code in order to see what you´ve done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage:
`localStorage.set('example','data');`

then in page two:
`console.log(localStorage.get('example'));`